# Do I need to cross-build my SBT plugin to both 1.0 and 1.1?

Tags: sbt, sbt-plugin

I have an SBT plugin that, in the past, I cross-built to 0.13.16 and 1.0.2. I'm going to release a new version soon, and I want to update these versions. Is it sufficient to say this?

```
crossSbtVersions := Vector("0.13.17", "1.1.6")
```

Or do I need to add 1.0.4 in there as well?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to cross-build for 1.0 and 1.1, because sbt follows semantic versioning (since 1.0) and any plugin working with 1.0 should work with 1.1. Therefore to ensure that your plugin will work well with all 1.x versions, you only need to build it with 1.0.4.